# JSON: use jq to edit specific values in nested arrays

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I'm trying to update values within an array inside an array using the utility jq. I've pasted the sample json below.

More specifically: Within the sheets array, and then within the formulas array, I'd like to change each columnName with a value of "MONTH" to "YEAR". I'd like to do the same for within the sheets array, within the columnStyles array, change each incidence of "MONTH" also to "YEAR"

This jq filter gets me the list of columnNames.

```
.sheets[1] | .formulas[] | .columnName
```

How can I edit the entire file in place by just updating the values I want? Do I use map with if?

And what if I wanted to edit a portion of a value? For example, in a forumlaString property, just changing the part of the string that contains MONTH but leaving the rest intact?

```
{
  "version": "6.1.1",
  "className": "xyz",
  "sheets": [    
  {
      "name": "Pass1",
      "sheetId": "95e6c2cd-abbe-46c1-8012-bdf37438b9b7",
      "keep": true,
      "formulas": [
        {
          "columnName": "SAMPLE_PROVIDER",
          "columnId": "0",
          "columnIndex": 0,
          "formulaString": "\u003dGROUPBY(#Raw!SAMPLE_PROVIDER)"
        },
        {
          "columnName": "MONTH",
          "columnId": "1",
          "columnIndex": 1,
          "formulaString": "\u003dGROUPBY(#Raw!MONTH)"
        }
      ],
      "columnStyles": [
        {
          "columnId": "0",
          "name": "SAMPLE_PROVIDER",
          "width": 206,
          "thousandSeparator": true
        },
        {
          "columnId": "1",
          "name": "MONTH",
          "width": 100,
          "thousandSeparator": true
        }
        ],
      "nextColumnId": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Transform1",
      "sheetId": "49071c1c-fa84-4ae3-92c1-b63175a6b26c",
      "keep": true,
      "formulas": [
        {
          "columnName": "SAMPLE_PROVIDER",
          "columnId": "0",
          "columnIndex": 0,
          "formulaString": "\u003d#Pass1!SAMPLE_PROVIDER"
        },
        {
          "columnName": "MONTH",
          "columnId": "1",
          "columnIndex": 1,
          "formulaString": "\u003d#Pass1!MONTH"
        }
      ],
      "columnStyles": [
        {
          "columnId": "0",
          "name": "SAMPLE_PROVIDER",
          "width": 179,
          "thousandSeparator": true
        },
        {
          "columnId": "1",
          "name": "MONTH",
          "width": 100,
          "thousandSeparator": true
        }
      ],
      "nextColumnId": 3
    }
  ],
  "advancedSchedulingInUse": true,
  "errorHandlingMode": "IGNORE"
}
```

Comment: Thanks chepner and hek2mgl!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the `columnName` field in the desired containers, you can use

```
jq '(.sheets[] | .formulas[]? | .columnName | select(.=="MONTH")) |= "YEAR"' tmp.json
```

(The `?` avoids an error if there is no key `formula`.)

To replace `MONTH` with `YEAR` in formula strings, replace each `formulaString` value with a possible modified string returned by `sub`.

```
jq '(.sheets[] | .formulas[]? | .formulaString) |= sub("MONTH"; "YEAR")' tmp.json
```

(`sub` requires `jq` 1.5, compiled with the Oniguruma library.)

To combine these into a single `jq` filter? I'm not sure yet; I have only a tenuous understanding of why either one alone works.

Comment: Which version of `jq` are you using?

Comment: Version 1.5 (which is required for the `sub` function).

Comment: Ah I see, after using the *right* syntax, meaning `sub(a; b)` instead of `sub(a, b)` I got: `jq was compiled without ONIGURUMA regex libary. match/test/sub and related functions are not available.`

Comment: I think the semicolon is used to separate arguments because `,` is an operator that feeds its input to the filters on its left and right (if that's what you mean). (Since `"MONTH"` and `"YEAR"` are just filters that ignore their input and return strings.)

Comment: Ah! I remember that now. The `,` separates multiple filters. Thanks!

Comment: Follow up question. What if one of the sheets array elements does not have a "formulas" array? Without accounting for this, I get the error "cannot iterate over null". Your example works fine when I remove the sheet with no formula section.

Comment: Just add a `?` to the filter that selects the `formulas` array: `... | .formulas[]? | ...`

Comment: I'm trying to get sub to work. Thus far I'm getting it to perform substitutions correctly, but the output is limited to just the value of "formulaString", but not the entire JSON. Using the select and |= operators is working on the entire JSON.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're updating more than just fields in the formulas arrays, but a little bit of everything.

If you want to indiscriminately change all occurrences of the string `"MONTH"` to `"YEAR"`, you could do this:

```
(.. | strings) |= sub("MONTH"; "YEAR")
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a task for walk/1.

(If your jq does not have walk/1, then you can copy its definition from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq)

For example, if you want to change "MONTH" to "YEAR" whenever "MONTH" appears as the value of a key in an object, then the following would do the job:

`jq 'walk(if type == "object" 
         then with_entries(.value |= (if . == "MONTH" then "YEAR" else . end)) 
         else . end)' input.json`

Equivalently:

`jq 'walk(if type == "object" 
         then with_entries(if .value == "MONTH" then .value = "YEAR" else . end)
         else . end)' input.json`

These can easily be modified in accordance with similar requirements.

Comment: Curious as to why you refer to`walk` as `walk/1`?

Comment: The /N indicates the arity is N.  That's the way the built-in function`builtins` reports the built-in filters, for good reason.